# Rails 4.2 set bundle_command for different environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

I used the `set :bundle_command` in my schedule.rb file to tell cron where to look for bundle. This is how it looks like:

```
 set :bundle_command, "/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/bundle exec"
```

I am using Arch Linux for development but i want to deploy it to an Ubuntu Server. There is the path slightly different. 
How can i make this environment independent?

This statement as is in any environment files gives me the `set method not found` error.g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent versions of `whenever`, `@environment` holds the current environment.

```
case @environment
when 'production'
  set :bundle_command, "/other_path/bundle exec"
else
  set :bundle_command, "/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/bundle exec"
end
```